# Optimising a graphic and animation intese layout

Tags: javascript, performance, image, optimization, repaint

I'm working on a website that uses a lot of large images and a lot of javascript.

Check it out here – http://joehamilton.info/1/1/

I've been trying to improve the performance and have had little success. I would just like to keep the frame rate smooth because sometimes it gets bogged down.

I thought it might have been code that was bogging it down but after discovering profiling in chrome it seems to the "paint" process that is slowing things down.

I'm just wondering what I could do to improve things. I'm open for any suggestions but I guess I was thinking along the lines of these things types of things:
• Will compressing the image files help?
• Would a 300px square repeating pattern image be faster to paint in a 900px square div than a 900px square image..

It's a large and complex site so I would rather not spend ages modifying things if it's not going to help.

Any expert raster image people out there?

Comment: Is it normal that when I scroll to the bottom I get an error ? CSS Line 389ish. It took very long to load, but when it was done loading it was pretty fast here.

Comment: yeah it's a bit of a mess. there are a few bugs I need to sort out

Comment: oh yeah... that was something i had in there to debug another issue!

Comment: takes about a minute to load on chrome, and no loading bar or anything. Then its a giant collage with a broken scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

For anything moving around you should use transitions and transforms rather than jquery animate and background-position as it will then be hardware accelerated in some browsers. It also avoids repainting so regularly. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/demos/speed.php is an example comparing the two techniques in an admittedly extreme case.

If you can't do that, ensure your animation uses requestAnimationFrame rather than a setTimeout loop.

That should help a lot.

Comment: hmm.. I'm reading in to it but there is a lot to wade through. How would I convert something like this so it uses a transform?  $('#p6bg').css('backgroundPosition', -scrollerCount/18+'px 0px');

Comment: $('#p6bg').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate('-scrollerCount/18+'px 0px)'); Should work. That won't have any animation though unless you add transitions as well. Also, you'll want to determine the vendor prefix, and use that.